# Value of argc changing after passing to function

Tags: function, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

Hi working on a simple linked list based program, currently the program accepts 2 command line arguments which I need to pass to another function in another file. After passing the arguments however, argc contains a completely different value. I don't alter it aside from passing. Any help would be appreciated!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "DrawTool.h"
#include "ListLib.h"
#include "FileLib.h"

#define MAX 35
#define MAP_SIZE 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char mapBase[MAXMAPSIZE][MAXMAPSIZE];
    int userSize;
    char drawCommand;
    int colInputNum;
    int rowInputNum;
    int lengthInputNum;
    char drawSymbol;
    char *Token;
    char Buffer[MAX];
    char letterString[MAX] = {};
    char commandString[MAX] = {};
    char tempString[MAX] = {};
    char *commandStrPtr;
    NODE *LinkedListHead = NULL;
    NODE *TempPtr = NULL;
    FILE *userFile;
    
    printf("\n the current value of argc is %d", argc);
    printf("\nThe file name should be %s", argv[1]);
    userFile = OpenFile(argc, argv);

    ReadFileIntoLinkedList(userFile, &*LinkedListHead);
    
    return 0;
} // end main
```

and the other file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ListLib.h"

FILE OpenFile(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    /* declare various variables needed */
    char *fileName = NULL;
    FILE *userFile;
    printf("\n the current value of argc is %d", argc);

    /* if argc is 2, then use argv[1] as the input file name, else print the message seen in sample output */
    if(argc == 2)
    {
        printf("\nargc is 2, this should set file name");
        printf("\nThis is the second check to make sure argv[1] made it. The file name should be %s", argv[1]);
        fileName = argv[1];
    }//end if check argc
    else
    {
        printf("\nMust be run with an input file name. ");
    }//end else reject

    do
    {   

        printf("\nThe file name has made it to file lib, the name of variable fileName is:  %s", fileName);
        /* open file with "r" mode */
        userFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
        /* if file did not open */
        if(userFile == NULL )
        {
            /* print message seen in sample output */
            /* read in new filename */
            /* open the file "r" mode */
            printf("\nCould not open input file named %s\nEnter a file name at the prompt ", userFile);
            scanf("%s", fileName);
            userFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

        }
    }
    while (userFile == NULL);

    /* return the file handle */
    return *userFile;
}
```

(Removed non-relevant snippets)
This is the current output I'm getting:
 `the current value of argc is 2 The file name should be input.txt the current value of argc is 1405392920 Must be run with an input file name. The file name has made it to file lib, the name of variable fileName is:  (null) Could not open input file named (null) Enter a file name at the prompt`

I'm not sure what to try as I'm a bit of a novice and I don't change the value at anytime. it reads my command line inputs correctly in the main function but after passing by value the value inside argc is completely different.

Comment: Do you have a declaration of `OpenFile()` in one of the header files included in your main program?  (`FileLib.h` I suppose.). If that doesn't match the actual definition of the function, incorrect parameter values are the least of the problems you can expect.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't include the header files since as to not crowd the post with too many code snippets. I can confirm that the header file matches the c file.

Comment: How can`main` take the `FILE` returned by `OpenFile` and store it in a `FILE*`? (Also, FILE objects should not be copied.) My guess is that the declaration in FileLib.h does not in fact match the c file.